# Fechar a pergunta mais antiga como duplicata ou não?

Tags: debate, perguntas-duplicadas

Uma pergunta mais antiga pode ser a duplicata de uma pergunta mais nova que tenha resposta?

Por exemplo, tenho duas perguntas que podem ser consideradas duplicatas (hipotéticas):

- Uma pergunta mais antiga que não possui resposta.
- Uma pergunta mais recente que já possui resposta aceita.

Eu poderia fechar a primeira que é mais antiga considerando ela como duplicata, já que a mais recente não tem resposta (considerando que não fui eu quem forneceu a resposta) ou eu devo fechar pela ordem da cronologia?

Em outras palavras a mais antiga mesmo sem resposta deve ficar aberta e neste caso eu devo fornecer uma resposta (se possível) e fechar as mais recente que já possuem respostas?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Eu diria que a ordem cronológica é irrelevante.

Se existe uma pergunta com uma boa resposta que aborda o mesmo problema que outra pergunta sem resposta então podemos marcar como duplicada.

Haverá sempre perguntas que não têm solução na altura, passados uns meses é criada uma pergunta semelhante e alguém sabe responder. Aí não faz sentido ir responder à mais antiga primeiro, esperar upvotes e depois tentar fechar a nova como duplicada.

Se fôr um caso muito bicudo podemos discutir aqui, senão sugiro seguir a regra da melhor resposta.

Comment: Concordo contigo. Obrigado.