# Perguntas duplicadas - Links e Sinonimos

Tags: novo-recurso, perguntas-duplicadas

Estava analisando algumas peculiaridades das perguntas duplicadas.

#### Situação

As duplicatas possuem link para original, ate ai tudo bem, mas notei que a original não possui paras as duplicatas (argumentarei sobre isso adiante).
As perguntas duplicatas são sinônimos para a original para a original, mas a original não exibe termos relacionados.

#### Ocorrências

Muitas vezes o AP (autor da pergunta) não sabe que a [pergunta já foi feita](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/1991/o-que-fazer-quando-notar-que-a-sua-pergunta-j%C3%A1-foi-feita-respondida-se-for-uma), contudo a comunidade na maioria das já analisa e [indica a duplicata](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/607/lidando-com-perguntas-duplicadas). Isso não impede que no intervalo de tempo entre ser mascada como duplicata alguém acabe por [responder a duplicata](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/3874/fechar-a-pergunta-mais-antiga-como-duplicata-ou-n%C3%A3o). Assim gerando conteúdos separados o que não é o ideal assim como [já discutido](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/2295/s%C3%B3-devo-votar-como-duplicata-as-perguntas-cujo-duplicado-j%C3%A1-tem-resposta).

São casos peculiares em que as duplicatas podem ter respostas melhores que a original. Mesmo sendo um casos creio que devem ser tratados.

#### Proposta

Creio as perguntas duplicadas deve ser um circulo e não um link, tanto original quanto duplicatas referenciassem as demais perguntas. Assim o leitor poderia ler todos os conteúdos relacionados, pois como já disse pode ser que alguma das duplicatas tenha um resposta melhor, assim como fornecer outros pontos de vista e abordagem para o leitor.

#### Desvantagens

- As perguntas teriam mais uma parte no topo para exibição das duplicatas, com vários linkes para as mesmas. (Minha sugestão seria uma `<div>` que o leitor clica-se para exibi-las ou não)

#### Vantagens

- Fornece muito mais recursos de leitura de soluções disponíveis para o leitor.
- Facilita as pesquisas de perguntas pois os termos relacionados também são considerados.

Comment: Não sei se gosto...