# Pergunta duplicada Proposital

Tags: suporte, perguntas-duplicadas

É um tanto irônico, mas após fazer [esta pergunta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4514/perguntas-duplicadas-links-e-sinonimos), fui estudar sobre [assincronismo](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/assincronismo), e cheguei [nesta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/16950/como-programa%C3%A7%C3%A3o-ass%C3%ADncrona-funciona-em-javascript).

A resposta esta bem dissertativa e eu tenho um pouco de dificuldade de entender, prefiro exemplos, como na citação sobre **tick**. Ainda assim me surgiram algumas duvidas sobre a questão abordada?

Como proceder?

- Realizar nova pergunta especificando os detalhes solicitados e fazendo referencia a mesma?
- Oferecer recompensar deixando um comentário para os detalhes solicitados?

Comment: Eu posso tentar melhorar minha resposta, mas não entendi bem o que você gostaria.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Acho que a pergunta em questão é extremamente ampla, e por mais que a resposta dada esteja super completa, **ela não vai conseguir cobrir todos os pontos**.

Você diz que ainda tem **dúvidas**, e eu imagino que elas possam facilmente se tornar perguntas distintas.

A resposta está na sua própria pergunta:

> *"Oferecer recompensa deixando um comentário para os **detalhes** solicitados?"*

Você procura detalhes - coisa que não foi pedida na pergunta original - e se fosse respondida desta maneira, transformaria a resposta em um livro.

**A grosso modo: Se você não fizer a mesma pergunta, ela não é duplicata.**

Comment: Removi seu recado ao bfavaretto pois deveria ser um comentário na pergunta (e `@usuario` não gera notificação dentro dos posts)

Comment: @brasofilo A intenção não era que ele fosse notificado, eu tenho esse conhecimento. Apesar de um pouco repetitiva, a frase fazia parte da resposta.